# Create filled contour map with GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, contour

### Background

I'm trying to make contour/isoline/isochrone maps to show what areas are within walking distance to schools for [my pet project to help with the Safe Routes to School program](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Safe_Routes_to_School_Mapping_Toolkit). I followed the pgRouting workshop and underdark's posts (all linked to from my project page) to import [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) into a [PostGIS](http://www.refractions.net/products/postgis/) database, then used the driving_distance() function to create a point layer that had a cost attribute, then ran the contour plugin of [Quantum GIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) to create contour lines, which I then styled in QGIS to create this image (pardon the spurious lines, not sure where they came from):

[image]

### What I'd like to do

**I'd like to replace the QGIS contour plugin and styling feature with GRASS**, as I'd like to create this image dynamically for a web service, and I don't think QGIS is meant for that (at least performance-wise, I think it may be possible with Python). So I'm trying to figure out how to do this same thing with [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/), which appears to be used quite a bit in web services.

From my reading, it appears I'll want to use something like [`v.surf.rst`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.surf.rst.html), though that seems like it would generate more of a heat map with a gradient, rather than the type of image shown above with solid colors for each band (in this case each band is 1/4 mile).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After using **v.surf.rst**, it's only a question about how to display the resulting cost raster.

GRASS offers [r.colors](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.colors.html) to specify a color map for a raster.
As far as I can see,  the normal behavior of GRASS is to interpolate colors, so you you'll have to work around this:

```
r.colors map=travel_costs color=rules 
0 green
100 green 
101 yellow
200 yellow
201 red 
300 red 
end
```

Comment: After getting v.surf.rst working correctly (I forgot to set the proper region), this worked perfectly. Thanks!