# Quickly create contour polygons from cost points using OSS for web app

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, open-source-gis, grass-gis, openstreetmap

This is related to a previous question I've asked:
[Create filled contour map with GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/create-filled-contour-map-with-grass)

I've created a point layer using OpenStreetMap data and pgRouting's driving_distance() function, where the points contain a cost attribute which contains the walking distance from a school. I've used QGIS and the contour plugin to create what I want:

[image: walking distance isolines]

**However I'd now like to do this programmatically for a web app, and in addition result in polygons rather than a raster.** I've got something working using GRASS, however it is quite slow, around 30 secs on my machine versus less than 1 sec using QGIS and the contour plugin. Here the short version (or see [Python version](https://gist.github.com/1186390)):

```
# read file and set resolution and bounds
v.in.ogr dsn=cost_points.shp output=cost_points
g.region vect=cost_points rows=256 cols=256
# interpolate points and make bands of 0.4km increments
v.surf.rst input=cost_points elev=interp zcolumn=cost
r.mapcalc res='int(interp/0.4)'
# convert to polygons and write out file
r.to.vect -s input=result output=polys feature=area
v.out.ogr -c input=polys dsn=polys.shp type=area
```

**Are there other GRASS functions I should use?** r.surf.rst takes the majority of the time, so perhaps it is too robust for my needs, but even then the results aren't smooth enough for my liking. **Are there other open source libraries I should be considering for this?**

If you'd like to know more about my overall goals, see [this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Safe_Routes_to_School_Mapping_Toolkit).

Comment: This is also possible in saga gis. Can you provide an example cost_points.shp file?  I can write a short script doing the same. It would be nice to see how the performance would differ from grass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I just took the code from the QGIS contour plugin and modified it for my purposes to accept and output any OGR supported formats. I can now have it spit out GeoJSON and display the vector layers (polygons) on an OpenLayers map. If interested, you can get the code on GitHub: [pysochrone](https://github.com/joshdoe/pysochrone).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For sure v.surf.rst is time consuming. Consider to use the much faster [v.surf.bspline](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.surf.bspline.html) instead. You may also replace, since you only have points, v.in.ogr with [v.external](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.external.html) which just registers the data source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've been playing with v.surf.bspline for a bit, but am having trouble getting sensible results. I think I need to better understand the parameters; I've varied the spline step, which changes the results significantly, but I haven't figured out what's the "right" number to use yet.

Comment: The manual page http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.surf.bspline.html suggests "For optimum performance, the length of spline step should be no less than the distance between observation points." - did you try this?

Comment: I read that, but the problem with my data is that the distance between points varies significantly, maybe between a meter and 50 meters or more. I haven't yet found a value that gives good results. Maybe I should find out what method the QGIS contour plugin uses.

Comment: You may want to check in v.surf.bspline this flag: "-e
  Estimate point density and distance for the input vector points within the current region extends and quit"