# Mann-Whitney U test for rasters

Tags: raster, spatial-statistics, statistics

I'm doing a Mann-Whitney U test to compare two very large samples (sample size 1 = 13250; samlple size 2 = 38871) originating from a shapefile with 52121 features. I know t-tests are not recommended to compare rasters, because since rasters have so many values, they will almost surely detect a significant difference, no matter how small that difference might be (see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66516/how-to-calculate-pairwise-t-test-and-correlation-between-raster-pixels-in-arcgis) post in gis.stackexchange.com and point 3 of the first answer to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72041/similarity-between-two-raster-maps)).

I ran the test on SPSS and got the following results:

- Test Statistics
- Mann-Whitney U    4094520,000
- Wilcoxon W    759591276,000
- Z -210,227
- Asymp. Sig. (2-tailed)    ,000

While I did expect to find a difference between the groups, I don't know what to make of such large values.

There is a paper which did the same thing I did. See the last sentence of the [Material and Methods section](http://icesjms.oxfordjournals.org/content/69/1/75.full#sec-2). However, they obtained much smaller values http://icesjms.oxfordjournals.org/content/69/1/75/T5.expansion.html (they don't make clear if these are Mann-Whitney Us or z-scores). Granted they used a smaller sample (combined sample size = 5629), but the difference in the magnitude of the values still seem strange to me.

**So, are my results simply the result of a very large sample, but still valid? Or should I use another test?**