# Polygon Between Contour Line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon-creation

I have a contour generated from SRTM,
[image]

How to fill the space between that contour with polygon (for all part) but it generates field in attribute table automaticaly, example in image above between contour 6 and 7 then the polygon generated should have custom field "nilai" with value "6-7" in attribute table.

I've tried polyline to polygon but it's not working I should enter the value of polygon manually, there are so many to be edited one by one.

**1st Method Using Spatial Analyst License (you can zoom in youre browser using "ctrl and +")**

1. Created Polygon (per 1m for 1m - 30m using feature to polygon tool) from contour created from dtm using **contour list** tool. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdBXL.png
   [image]
2. This is my DTM raster https://i.stack.imgur.com/mez5C.png
   [image]
3. Creating Zonal using **Zonal Statistic as Table** tool https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieJlz.png
   [image]
4. Zonal result attribute table https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w8iG.png
   [image]
5. Join polygon with zonal result https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDhA6.png
   [image]
6. Attribute Table of joined result https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Ve5.png
   [image]
7. Checking the result after i **round** it, from that result maximum and minimum value are not match with the contour line https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Gdb.png
   [image]

**2nd Method Using Spatial Analyst License**
I use this script provide by Michael

```
import sys, os, arcpy

InPolygons = sys.argv[1]
NearContour = sys.argv[2]
OutPolygons = sys.argv[3]

ElevationFieldName = "contour" # change this to match your field name

InFolder = os.path.dirname(InPolygons) # the folder the input is in
Working = InFolder + "\\Working.gdb"
WorkingContour = Working+"\\Contour"
WorkingPoly = Working+"\\Poly"

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(InFolder,"Working.gdb") # create a working space
arcpy.AddMessage("Copy 1")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(NearContour,WorkingContour) # need to do this to take charge of names
arcpy.AddMessage("Copy 2")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(InPolygons,WorkingPoly) 

# remove 'bad' edges, tagged with elevation = -9999 to show they are a boundary
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(WorkingContour,"Remove",ElevationFieldName + " = -9999")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("Remove")
arcpy.Delete_management("Remove") # relax, it's just removing the layer, just to keep it clean

# Create a near table
arcpy.AddMessage("Near table")
arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(WorkingPoly,WorkingContour,Working+"\\NearTable","0",closest="ALL")
arcpy.AddField_management(Working+"\\NearTable","Elev","DOUBLE")

try:
    arcpy.AddIndex_management(Working+"\\NearTable","NEAR_FID","NEAR_FID")
except:
    arcpy.AddWarning("Unable to index")

# join and copy elevations
arcpy.AddMessage("Join & calc")
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(Working+"\\NearTable","View")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("View","NEAR_FID",WorkingContour,"OBJECTID")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("View","NearTable.Elev","!Contour."+ElevationFieldName+"!","PYTHON")
arcpy.Delete_management("View") # relax, it's just removing the table view, just to keep it clean

# remove join and summary statistics
arcpy.AddMessage("Make stats")
#arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("View")
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Working+"\\NearTable",Working+"\\NearStats",[["Elev","MIN"],["Elev","Max"]],"IN_FID")

# copy the min and max to the working contours
arcpy.AddMessage("Copy min/max")
arcpy.AddField_management(WorkingPoly,"MinElev","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(WorkingPoly,"MaxElev","DOUBLE")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(WorkingPoly,"Layer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("Layer","OBJECTID",Working+"\\NearStats","IN_FID")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Layer","Poly.MinElev","!NearStats.Min_Elev!","PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Layer","Poly.MaxElev","!NearStats.Max_Elev!","PYTHON")
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("Layer")
arcpy.Delete_management("Layer") # relax, it's just removing the layer, just to keep it clean

# check for field
arcpy.AddMessage("Checking for field")
Fields = arcpy.ListFields(WorkingPoly,"nilai")
if not Fields:
    arcpy.AddMessage("-Adding field")
    arcpy.AddField_management(WorkingPoly,"nilai","TEXT",field_length="10")

# format the field with the min and max,
# this could be done with a field calculation
# but in this case I want a special case for isolations
arcpy.AddMessage("Cursoring")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(WorkingPoly,("nilai","MinElev","MaxElev")) as UpCur:
    for Feat in UpCur:
        if (Feat[1]==Feat[2]):
            # values are the same = an isolation
            Feat[0] = str(int(Feat[1]))
        else:
            Feat[0] = "%d - %d" % (Feat[1],Feat[2])
        UpCur.updateRow(Feat)

arcpy.AddMessage("Copy out")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(WorkingPoly,OutPolygons)
```

*Processing :*
[image]

*Result* https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF21X.png
[image]

**I use 2nd Method, it takes a long time but it work. Thanks.**

Comment: cover with a bounding box and use feature to polygon to make the polygons and then you just need to find the bounding line information, this could be done in a python script.

Comment: Thanks, so what should i do is I convert first with feature to polygon tool (I get it until here)
but the next problem is (as you know before) I'm bad at python... any clue?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it but it will take a long time. You need to select by location (contours bounding each polygon) and then find out which one is lower and if you have any higher ignoring the bounding box (summary statistics can do this) and then calculate the values. It's not difficult just tedious.

Comment: I wrote a program to do this in AML and ported it to VB.net; the area between contours are *hypsometric areas* and they can be shaded as hypsometric tints but only if you know the elevation... anyway, coverages have excellent topology if you can find a way to generate one it's easy to cursor through but still quite tedious.

Comment: So I guess I ended up doing manually... *duh

Comment: How many contours have you got? Is it going to be a big problem to do it manually? Since Esri moved away from polygon::arc::label topology these sorts of things are a lot more difficult.

Comment: It's about 30 thousand contour line (with elevation per 1m from 1m until 30m)... that's why I wanted it to be automatically (*duh... another bad news) Now I'm really shocked..

Comment: I'll put something together but I'm under the pump today so it could take a while. No way would I do that manually!

Comment: Yeah... I know that feel...., It's really a pain even just to imagine that.. anyway Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this may be a possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61550/colouring-areas-between-vector-contours

Comment: That's a great idea @PolyGeo, I was progressing with generate near table, copy elevations, summary statistics.... which is taking a long time to complete. If you have spatial analyst look at Zonal Statistics http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000 to get your min/max and then just int that like nilai = str(int(!min!)) + " - " + str(int(!max!))

Comment: You could just use Manifold to do this ("areas" is a basic contour option) if you're not wedded to ArcGIS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you've created the polygons by closing the ends (closing lines are given elevation of -9999 so they're removed and not factored into the min and max) and using [Feature to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003n000000) then added your field (*nilai* as text):

```py
import sys, os, arcpy

InPolygons = sys.argv[1]
NearContour = sys.argv[2]
OutPolygons = sys.argv[3]

ElevationFieldName = "Elevation" # change this to match your field name

InFolder = os.path.dirname(InPolygons) # the folder the input is in
Working = InFolder + "\\Working.gdb"
WorkingContour = Working+"\\Contour"
WorkingPoly = Working+"\\Poly"

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(InFolder,"Working.gdb") # create a working space
arcpy.AddMessage("Copy 1")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(NearContour,WorkingContour) # need to do this to take charge of names
arcpy.AddMessage("Copy 2")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(InPolygons,WorkingPoly) 

# remove 'bad' edges, tagged with elevation = -9999 to show they are a boundary
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(WorkingContour,"Remove",ElevationFieldName + " = -9999")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("Remove")
arcpy.Delete_management("Remove") # relax, it's just removing the layer, just to keep it clean

# Create a near table
arcpy.AddMessage("Near table")
arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(WorkingPoly,WorkingContour,Working+"\\NearTable","0",closest="ALL")
arcpy.AddField_management(Working+"\\NearTable","Elev","DOUBLE")

try:
    arcpy.AddIndex_management(Working+"\\NearTable","NEAR_FID","NEAR_FID")
except:
    arcpy.AddWarning("Unable to index")

# join and copy elevations
arcpy.AddMessage("Join & calc")
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(Working+"\\NearTable","View")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("View","NEAR_FID",WorkingContour,"OBJECTID")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("View","NearTable.Elev","!Contour."+ElevationFieldName+"!","PYTHON")
arcpy.Delete_management("View") # relax, it's just removing the table view, just to keep it clean

# remove join and summary statistics
arcpy.AddMessage("Make stats")
#arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("View")
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Working+"\\NearTable",Working+"\\NearStats",[["Elev","MIN"],["Elev","Max"]],"IN_FID")

# copy the min and max to the working contours
arcpy.AddMessage("Copy min/max")
arcpy.AddField_management(WorkingPoly,"MinElev","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(WorkingPoly,"MaxElev","DOUBLE")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(WorkingPoly,"Layer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("Layer","OBJECTID",Working+"\\NearStats","IN_FID")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Layer","Poly.MinElev","!NearStats.Min_Elev!","PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Layer","Poly.MaxElev","!NearStats.Max_Elev!","PYTHON")
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("Layer")
arcpy.Delete_management("Layer") # relax, it's just removing the layer, just to keep it clean

# check for field
arcpy.AddMessage("Checking for field")
Fields = arcpy.ListFields(WorkingPoly,"nilai")
if not Fields:
    arcpy.AddMessage("-Adding field")
    arcpy.AddField_management(WorkingPoly,"nilai","TEXT",field_length="10")

# format the field with the min and max,
# this could be done with a field calculation
# but in this case I want a special case for isolations
arcpy.AddMessage("Cursoring")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(WorkingPoly,("nilai","MinElev","MaxElev")) as UpCur:
    for Feat in UpCur:
        if (Feat[1]==Feat[2]):
            # values are the same = an isolation
            Feat[0] = str(int(Feat[1]))
        else:
            Feat[0] = "%d - %d" % (Feat[1],Feat[2])
        UpCur.updateRow(Feat)

arcpy.AddMessage("Copy out")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(WorkingPoly,OutPolygons)
```

Using [Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000) with a 0 tolerance to find the link between polygons and their bounding lines. To the near table add a field to store the elevations of the lines they describe, then it's just a matter of getting the statistics for min and max elevations in the near table for each unique input FID (polygon) then joining to the polygons and populating the field.

The tool [Generate Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000) will take a very long time to run, so try to do it overnight; I have tested this code with 350 polygons and 345 lines which took about 10 minutes to complete.

Isolations (only one elevation for min and max) will have just their value populated, intermediate polygons will be populated with min - max in that field.

## Alternate (Spatial Analyst) method, much faster

If you have a spatial analyst license and the raster the contours came from you can follow the workflow in [Colouring areas between (vector) contours?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61550/colouring-areas-between-vector-contours) as translated for Esri and performed interactively in ArcMap:

Use the [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) tool to create a table using the polygons as input zones and FID (OBJECTID) as the zone field, I used statistics type "ALL" to avoid confusion later. This gives you a table with the raster statistics (min & max) for each polygon - and it's really fast!

Add fields to the polygons for the minimum and maximum elevation and then join the zonal statistics table (join in ArcMap polygon FID to ZonalTable ObjectID_1 or FID_1 depending on table type, either way it should be the second field in the zonal stats table) to your polygon and use the calculation like this:

```
MinElev = round( !ZonalStatsObjectID.MIN!,0 )
MaxElev = round( !ZonalStatsObjectID.MAX!,0 )
```

The name of the zonal statistics table in this example is ZonalStatsObjectID, change to match your table name. Do NOT use `int( !ZonalStatsObjectID.MIN!)`, that's a truncation and will give you the wrong value.

After rounding and copying the values for min and max use field calculator on the table to calculate the nilai field:

```
def CalcNilai(Min,Max):
    if Min == Max:
        return "%d" % Min
    else:
        return "%d - %d" % (Min,Max)
```

Which should look like this (I've removed the join for simplicity):
[image]

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write this out, and for documenting it so well with good comments

Comment: Thanks @StephenLead, I had already written it and was testing it when PolyGeo commented on the other post. Considering you would need spatial analyst to perform Zonal Statistics (and it was already written) I posted it anyway. The raster method would be much quicker but this works.

Comment: Actually I have spatial analyst license (but still cant understand the step in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61550/colouring-areas-between-vector-contours, but still this amaze me... It's a complicate code, I'll try first, Thanks for helping me.. again.

Comment: You're welcome.. again. Have a look at the edits, I've taken the key points from the other post and put them in Esri tools; on the same test data I had it done in under a minute! There is of course a very small chance of getting incorrect value using a raster but it should be good enough.

Comment: For faster processing I tried the spatial analyst first but it seems the result is not like I expect (I have dtm and contour file). At the edits, I put all my process to do and the result there. If python have less chance getting incorrect value than spatial analyst then I'll use python. can you show me the configurated python for me? I test that python code but I get an error (of course it's my fault, because I haven't configurated it yet)

Comment: I think you've hit the main problem with the spatial analyst method. Contours are placed approximately where values change and the area between may encounter a higher or lower value which is included when you do Zonal Statistics. When I did it I got the values I intended. I have tried to look through your workflow but the images are unreadable, can you attach the full sized ones as a link please and I'll have a look at them. Did the python method finish? if so was the result what you're after?

Comment: I'm sorry I should explain it more detail in my question about the image you can zoom youre browser It's easier for you than to open the image one by one.(but I've provide link too), question and python result shown in edited question.

Comment: Your process looks exactly like mine except I did it in a geodatabase and not a shape/dbf. To use the python script you need to read http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000001r000000 - all 3 arguments are of type *feature class*. You need to copy the code into notepad, save as py file and add to a toolbox then you can run it like any other tool. I use command line which is a little off-putting for some people but that works too.

Comment: I already did that before (have a toolbox, and .py file), but still generates that error...
Whats this "Assuming you've created the polygons by closing the ends" mean? Isn't the polygon already closed at the end? This is my small part of the contour and polygon https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzTrGTReNp4mTnE2ZGtadnFESlE/edit?usp=sharing
I think I misconfigurated it with my shape, but I dont know which part....

Comment: There's an error on line 1, there should be no characters before *import sys, os, arcpy*. Contours are created as lines and are usually open at the ends so don't make polygons, you need (and it looks like you have) to ensure that the contours make complete polygons with no gaps - as you have an island the contours go all the way around and will make nice polygons but if you try this on data that isn't an island you will have to draw a box around to ensure the contours close to polygons.

Comment: It's an island contours, and have a closed line at the contour file, already check the polygon, but got new error. updated question.

Comment: The script requires 3 parameters: Input Polygons, Input Contour Lines as input then Output Polygons as output. The error is telling you that it expects an argument but none is supplied in the tool. Have a close look at the link I provided two comments ago about inserting arguments or run on command line.

Comment: Yes, It's like what I expect, and it perfectly without an error. It takes a long time to process but it's worth it than have to check it again for very small chance of getting incorrect value using a raster. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you help me here? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114952/export-multiple-raster-data-with-custom-cell-size

Comment: I had another problem now, sometimes it stucks in Near Table process (message: Processed 1 features...) and it last more than 2 days, sometimes if I'm lucky It works in a night. I've cliped in to small piece area but still it stuck in Processed 1 Feature. Any solution?

Comment: Check your min and max values, if they're a text field you could have problems converting. Look for NULL values, that will cause the program to hang. If you are still experiencing the problem with numeric and non-null values it is likely to be a table blocking situation - close all Esri programs, wait for five minutes for them to fully exit, start a single instance of ArcMap and try again... if it still doesn't work it's probably an aggressive anti-virus or system task, reboot and try again.