# Exporting Multiple Raster Data with custom Cell Size using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I Have 172 Raster, and need to change the cellsize. So I use Export Data from TOC
[image]

and change the cellsize manually (example I want to change it to "3") 
[image]

I tried using this python script to create input and output folder (because batch output in resample had to be filled one by one and I just want to **let all value as default including file name** except for cellsize)

```
import sys, os, arcpy

InRaster = sys.argv[1]
OutRaster = sys.argv[2]

InFolder = os.path.dirname(InRaster)
arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

for Ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
    arcpy.AddMessage("Processing " + Ras)
    #arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(InFolder + "\\" + Ras , OutRaster ,"TIFF")
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(InFolder + "\\" + Ras , OutRaster+ "\\" + Ras ,"DEFAULTS","","","","","")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Done")
```

Setting Properties :
[image]

When I try to add Input folder and Output Folder it has different submit
[image]

[image]

Result in error :
[image]

Is there any way to do it automatically or fixed for my python code to process multiple raster at once?

Comment: This looks related (just needs to modify output cellsize rather than format) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107700/export-raster-data-to-tiff-bmp-or-png-file-using-python

Comment: where should I put the cellsize command in arcpy.CopyRaster_management(in_raster, out_rasterdataset) ?

Comment: geoprocessing > environment setting >raster analysis, but I recommend my answer which is more specific to your problem ;-)

Comment: From its tool documentation you will see it has a lot of other parameters but it does not have cell size after all (my mistake).  The answer by @radouxju looks right to me.

Comment: Can I join the command using script from here? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000

Comment: The error you're getting is *unexpected indent* which can be hard to pick... perhaps you're using spaces for indents and then line 11 starts with a tab. A good editor like PyWin will show you tabs/spaces. Seriously though I'd use GDAL_Translate or QGIS raster export with batch mode.

Comment: Updated script, Actually I do this so that I can view the raster in QGIS. It's to heavy for opening in QGIS in that raster current condition.

Comment: You've got a different error. It appears that you're only specifying the *OutFolder* where it should be *OutFolder + "\\" + Ras*... the full path and *name* of the output raster. To help display faster in QGIS use GDALaddO to build the pyramids: gdaladdo -ro c:\some\path\raster.tif 2 4 8 16 32 would be the simplest; don't forget if the path contains spaces it needs to be quoted: "c:\some path\raster.tif" - that's a DOS convention.

Comment: Updated script and result. Already tried gdaladdo but no luck, already use qgis translate work for resize but not for position. anyway i took the command from resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//… I just need to change cellsize and let everything default

Answer (score 2):

For full control on the change of cell size, you can use the [Resample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009t000000) tool (data management). You can then select the best resampling method for your dataset (most of the time, your best choice will be MAJORITY for categorical data and CUBIC for continuous data).

You can run this tool in batch by right-clicking (> Batch...). You can then select all your files with "browse", then you enter the new cell size on the first row and you right click on this row (> "fill") in order to assign the same cell size for all rasters.

Comment: which resampling method should I use, I just want to change the cellsize but leave any other than that as default. and about output dataset, should I define it one by one? if yes, then it's the same with manually export it one by one. Basically I want to change only cellsize of multiple raster automatically and leave the rest as default including filenames.