# Find Average Elevation - ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation, line, topography

I am working with 2 shapefiles. One contains the boundaries of a city, the other contains polylines representing the topographic features of the area. Essentially, the polylines make a topographic map.

I want to calculate the average elevation of the city. I have some basic GIS knowledge, so I can select out just the polylines in the city... but I'm not sure how to determine the city's average elevation using this data? I could average the polylines together controlling for their length, but that's not quite accurate - a long line that goes around a lake contains a lot more area at the same elevation than a long line that goes around a big hill, for example.

Suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You would be a lot better off using a DEM and using Zonal Statistics if you have Spatial Analyst.

Comment: As @jbchurchill remarks, you need a digital elevation model (DEM) to do this, period. Although it's possible to create one from the contour lines, that is a time-consuming and [problematic](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61550/colouring-areas-between-vector-contours) exercise. Freely available DEMs at moderate to high resolution (100 meters would work just fine in most urban areas) now exist for every city in the world.

Comment: Thanks guys. Ended up finding a LIDAR raster file and using that. It was pretty simple at that point.